# What the meaning of StructName.init of Swift language?

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm

I am reading the iOS, MVVM sample project,
and I don't know what syntax is

What is **ArticleViewModel.init** of this code?

```
self.articlesVM = articles.compactMap(ArticleViewModel.init)
```

ArticleViewModel needs an argument to initialize.

What is the meaning of StructName.init?
I couldn't google, please help if you know.

```
struct ArticleListViewModel {
    let articlesVM: [ArticleViewModel]
}

extension ArticleListViewModel {

    init(_ articles: [Article]) {
        self.articlesVM = articles.compactMap(ArticleViewModel.init)
    }

}

struct ArticleViewModel {

    let article: Article

    init(_ article: Article) {
        self.article = article
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass `.init` as a closure, that's just shorthand to passing the closure argument to the init.

So `articles.compactMap(ArticleViewModel.init)` is shorthand for `articles.compactMap { ArticleViewModel.init($0) }` (where you wouldn't really write out `.init`, but use the shorthand notation `ArticleViewModel($0)`).

Comment: You're not "passing `.init` to a closure". You're passing the initialize *as* a closure.

Answer (score 1):

The key is to take a look what argument compactMap is taking:

```
public func compactMap<ElementOfResult>(_ transform: (Element) throws -> ElementOfResult?) rethrows -> [ElementOfResult]
```

As Apple's docs says, *"transform - is a closure that accepts an element of this sequence as its argument and returns an optional value."*

`ArticleViewModel.init` is also a closure which takes Article parameters as input:

```
init(_ article: Article) {
    self.article = article
}
```

That's why you can pass the reference to this closure as an argument to `compactMap`

```
articles.compactMap(ArticleViewModel.init)
```

`compactMap` call will loop trough the each element of `articles` array and automatically pass each individual element to the provided `ArticleViewModel.init` closure as argument. This closure will create an instance of `ArticleViewModel` from each `Article` object it receives and if created `ArticleViewModel` object is not nil, put/add it to the `self.articlesVM` array.

The exact same thing can be achieved by using more explicit code which performs the same result:

```
self.articlesVM = articles.compactMap { article in
    ArticleViewModel(article)
}
```

**P.S.** Since initialiser of `ArticleViewModel` always return object and can't return `nil`, it doesn't make sense here to use `compactMap`. You can use regular `map` instead:

```
self.articlesVM = articles.map { article in
    ArticleViewModel(article)
}
```

or shorter

```
self.articlesVM = articles.map { ArticleViewModel($0) }
```

or even more short

```
self.articlesVM = articles.map(ArticleViewModel.init)
```

Answer (score 0):

`compactMap` requires a function that takes an `Article` and return *something*.

`init(_ article: Article) { self.article = article }` takes an `Article` and returns *something*

So you can use it (`ArticleViewModel.init`) there.

So powerful, so simple.